# kubuntu xenial (kubuntu 16.04) does not seem to remember all settings after restart

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

Typically, I have various terminals open as I prefer working on the command line. However, upon log off/ shut down and log in again, all terminals in Kubuntu Xenial Xerus have vanished.

Earlier versions (at least until 14.04) restored all these settings.

How can I ensure that the last configuration of such stuff as number and position of terminals open is established again?

Remark: I have installed xenial on a Lenovo Thinkpad 510. I have installed it (in the 32-bit version) on an old IBM-Thinkpad T43 too. No such issue is present there, the desktop config seems to be restored perfectly in this case.

Thanks a lot for any hints.

PS added: "System settings -> Desktop Settings" has the option "on login - Restore previous session". This has been activated -no effect: Kubuntu Xenial starts with an empty session. Probably a bug?

Comment: Isn't there an option to "save session" or something in the KDE control center?

Comment: Hm, as far as I know, this is now called "system settings".  There is the sub menu "Desktop Behavior".  Under "Activities", I find "Default", and ""Desktop" items. "Remember the current desktop virtual desktop for each activity (needs restart)" is active. (Unsure whether this helps.)

Answer (score 0):

Session restore still does not work with Kubuntu 16.04.1.

It looks like this bug:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354724

It is supposed to be fixed with Plasma 5.6 for Qt applications.